# Why are the penguins flashing rainbow?

Tags: neo-the-world-ends-with-you

On Week 3 Day 6, while battling noise in Scramble Crossing, I started a fight with some penguins that were sparkling and glowing rainbow colors. The effect looked similar to a starman from Mario, only without the invincibility.

Why were these penguins sparkling and flashing rainbow colors?

[image: Rainbow glowing penguins]
<sub>Gameplay from [Week 3 Day 6 walkthrough](https://youtu.be/vohGgrKDAGE?t=1560) by ArcticViper</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The red-and-black penguin in your screenshot is no mere popguin, but a Brit Popguin, ruler of popguinkind, who notably "[will continue to power up its allies as long as it's on the battlefield](https://game8.co/games/NEO-TWEWY/archives/338726)." The glowing shows that the Electro Popguins are being powered up by their emperor.  Erase the crown-wearing noise to make the glow fade out.